# Is 2+3 considered as a literal?

Tags: literals

Suppose i have something like

```
int x = 2 + 3;
```

Is `x` considered to be a literal?

Answer (score 16):

`x` is a symbol. `2 + 3` is an expression. `2` and `3` are literals.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's two literals in a compile-time constant expression.  Depending on how it gets compiled, you may not be able to tell the difference in the resulting binary.

Comment: In C (and related languages) you _can_ use `2+3` in most places where you would use a “literal”, but that’s because what you’re actually using is a “constant expression” as Andrew points out.

Answer (score 8):

- int - type of the variable, identifier
- x   - name of the variable, identifier
- =   - assignment
- **2   - literal**
- +   - operation between two literals
- **3   - literal**
- ;   - end of the statement

Answer (score 1):

- **int** is a type
- **x** is an identifier
- **=,+** are operators
- **2,3** are literals as **"StringLiteral"** would be

To learn how all these syntacically elements are named you could browse i.g.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html

Answer (score 1):

yeah it is a literal. the expression will be reduced to literal, i.e. even before the program is run, so it is literal

other types of literal you might see in real-world (the programmer can't be bothered too compute it by himself, let the compiler do the grunt work of determining the literal):

const unsigned int NEGATIVE_TESTER_FOR_32_BIT = 1 << 31;

const char ALPHABET_PIVOT = 'A' + ( ('Z' - 'A') / 2);

**[EDIT: regarding depending on the compiler]**
yeah it depends on the compiler.  but i guess most of compiler writers do their homework, if they can generate the necessarily assembly or virtual machine instruction of the language, computing things in compile time is just a walk in the park for them.  in fact, even the character literal 'H' for example, doesn't even get stored in file as verbatim **'H'**, it gets stored as number literal (72, or in hex view 0x48 or 48h) in final machine code.  i can hazard a guess that all compilers will reduce the two literals to a literal, not expression. it's a walk in the park for them(compiler writers)