# Are operations like `2*7` considered literals?

Tags: literals

I just had a small question.

Are operations considered literals? Would `2*7`, for example, be a literal? Is `"hello, " + "world!"` a literal?

I know the operands are literals, but the expression is not explicitly `14` or `"hello, world!"`.

The question [Is 2+3 considered as a literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800696/is-23-considered-as-a-literal)
 asks basically what I am asking but most answers weren't even helpful, all they do is break the variable declaration down or talk about what compilers do with them, but I'm not looking for that, so I would like a more in depth explanation.

---

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the language and the compiler, sorry. But just using the concept that a literal is a kind of token, then no, the result is a compile-time constant, not a token.

In C/C++ 2*7 will be optimised by the compiler to make a new constant but it isn't actually legally defined as a literal, though it can be treated as a compile-time constant.

Concatenating `"hello" "world"` (note no plus) is actually described as a preprocessing step in c++, so does generate a new literal constant string, but then in original C this didn't work.

But note that in C, a macro will treat the parameter phrase `2+7` as separate tokens, and `#define STUPIDMUL3(val) 3 * val` for `2+7` will give the answer 13, not 18. If you could find a way to force macros to treat the two halves of the string differently, I think it would.

I would expect an interpreter to take longer to process 2*7 than it would 14 because it might interpret and solve it every time.